# How to eliminate excessive white space on top of page when printing PDF?

Tags: pdf, printing, zebra-printers

I am generating a PDF that appears perfect on the monitor, but when I print it, it has excessive white space at the top.

The page cuts off at the appropriate page on the bottom, but I am left with 3" of blank white space at the top.

It is a thermal heat printer, Swecoin Zebra Technogies TTP 2030.

Comment: What printer driver are you using?  Is it a necessity to print whatever you are printing as a pdf?

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I am using the driver provided by the vendor (which I don't know what it is).  Yes, it is required to print in PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using a different driver to see if that helps.  I know a lot of label printing companies have their own printer drivers that you may try.

http://www.seagullscientific.com/aspx/free-windows-printer-drivers-download.aspx

Try the drivers out above.  Usually you just download a package of drivers (Zebra, Printronix etc) and it unzips them to a directory on your hard drive called C:\Seagull.  They have their own printer driver installation wizard to install them.  It's almost identical to the windows printer driver wizard.  You could probably use the windows printer driver wizard and just point it toward the drivers in that directory but it's just as easy to use their driver wizard.